# What's the .NET Standard equivalent for PowerLineStatus from Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net-standard

Trying to convert a project from .NET Framework to .NET Standard, and we have a call to `PowerLineStatus`, but this seems to come from Windows Forms. Is there an equivalent one can call?

Comment: I don't think there is one that is .Net Standard.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the .NET Reference Source, the SystemInformation.PowerStatus class is just a wrapper around a call to the Win32 function GetSystemPowerStatus[^].

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        public static extern bool GetSystemPowerStatus([In, Out] ref NativeMethods.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS systemPowerStatus);
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5280702/How-do-I-check-for-the-status-of-my-laptop-battery

Comment: Where does `NativeMethods.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS` come from though?